# How to store a selected File(any file) in SQL Azure Table?

Tags: azure-sql-database

How to store a selected file (any file like .doc,.txt,.jpg or .xaml) in SQL Azure Table? And
What would be the size limit for the file.

i m using :
 1. RIA Services 
 2. Silverlight as a front end.
 3. SQL Azure for storage.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you use Azure storage to do so. Blobs in particular. you could access the blob contents through a URI over an http connection.